# how to 'for f loop' and remove blank lines

Tags: bash

I am connecting to macOSX shell and running a bash command to scan info.plist and print the results however, i am getting some blank lines

```
for f in $(find . -name 'Info.plist'); do grep -A 1 -e CFBundleIdentifier -e CFBundleVersion $f 2>/dev/null | awk -F "[<>]" '{print $3}'; done
```

```
for f in $(find . -name 'Info.plist'); do grep -A 1 -E 'CFBundleIdentifier|CFBundleVersion' $f 2>/dev/null | awk -F "[<>]" '{print $3}'; done
```

Result:

```
CFBundleIdentifier
com.apple.xcode.dsym.com.app.app1

CFBundleVersion
2.16.0.4386
CFBundleIdentifier
com.apple.xcode.dsym.app.app1Additions

CFBundleVersion
1
```

The issue appears to be with the Grep -e or -E. If i do only one grep and print the next line using -A 1, i don't get any spaces

Result without multiple greps:

```
for f in $(find . -name 'Info.plist'); do grep -A 1 CFBundleIdentifier $f 2>/dev/null | awk -F "[<>]" '{print $3}'; done
```

Result:

```
CFBundleIdentifier
com.apple.xcode.dsym.com.app.app1
CFBundleIdentifier
com.apple.xcode.dsym.app.app1Additions
```

How can i better scan info.plist and print the CFBundleIdentifier + next line and CFBundleIdentifier + next line and get a result

1. Without the space
2. A space after each info.plist

Expected Result:

```
CFBundleIdentifier
com.apple.xcode.dsym.com.app.app1
CFBundleVersion
2.16.0.4386
<Actual real space>
CFBundleIdentifier
com.apple.xcode.dsym.app.app1Additions
CFBundleVersion
1
```

Update 1:

Adding a full Info.plist for review

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.xcode.dsym.com.app.app1/string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>dSYM</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>2.16.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2.16.0.4385</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: Please read [Bash FAQ 001](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) first.

Comment: If we don't know what the files listed in `Info.plist` look like, we don't know what you're operating on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the root problem is that some of the Info.plist files are in the binary form of property list format, rather than the XML form, so `grep` is printing a bunch of lines like:

```
Binary file ./some/path/to/Info.plist matches
```

... and then `awk` tries to print the third field (sort of) but there isn't anything relevant there.

In order to solve this, you need to stop using `grep` and `awk`, and use a tool that actually understands the property list format (in all its forms), like `defaults` or `PlistBuddy`. `defaults` has some issues with how file paths are specified, so I'll vote for `PlistBuddy`.

Also, as @chepner and @EdMorton pointed out, the `for` loop over `find`'s output is not a safe way to handle filenames, especially on macOS where spaces in filenames are common. `PlistBuddy` would be easy to use directly with `find ... -exec`, but since you want a blank line after each file it's more complicated. Probably the easiest way to do that is with a `while read` loop (using null-delimited filenames to avoid trouble with spaces etc):

```
find . -name 'Info.plist' -print0 |
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
        /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print CFBundleIdentifier" -c "print :CFBundleVersion" "$file" 2>/dev/null
        echo
    done
```

Note that this will not print the "CFBundleIdentifier" and "CFBundleVersion" lines, just the data in those property list elements. If you want those names, yet another complication because you have to test whether those items are actually present in the plist.

Comment: So this works but when i add it to plink, it fails with File Doesn't Exist, Will Create: CFBundleIdentifier Invalid Arguments     
  




%Tools%\plink.exe -ssh -l ssh -pw testlab1234 10.162.8.45 "(find . -name 'Info.plist' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print CFBundleIdentifier" -c "print :CFBundleVersion" "$file" 2>/dev/null; echo; done)"

Answer (score 0):

The blank lines are coming from lines that don't have anything in the third field. So check for that in `awk`.

```
for f in $(find . -name 'Info.plist'); do 
    grep -A 1 -E 'CFBundleIdentifier|CFBundleVersion' $f 2>/dev/null | 
        awk -F "[<>]" '$NF >= 3 {print $3}'
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any sample input so this is a guess but you appear to just be trying to find a couple of strings and print the 3rd field from the line containing that string and the line after it. If so that'd just be:

```
find . -name 'Info.plist' -exec \
    awk -F'[<>]' '/CFBundle(Identifier|Version)/{c=2} c&&c--{print $3}' {} +
```

If your `find` doesn't support `+` as an arg then use `\;` instead.

You might want to read https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219, https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes, http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor as they address some of the other problems with your script.